# Transform NA values based on first value registration

Tags: r, na

I have some data like this:

```
    Date 1   Date 2    Date 3    Date 4    Date 5
  A  NA       0.1       0.2       NA        0.3
  B  0.1      NA        NA        0.3       0.2
  C  NA       NA        NA        NA        0.3
  D  0.1      0.2       0.3       0.1       NA
  E  NA       NA        0.1       0.2       0.1
```

I would like to change the `NA` values of my data based on the first date a value is registered. So for example for A, the first registration is Date 2. Then I want that before that registration the values of NA in A are 0, and after the first registration the values of `NA` become the mean of the registered values. 
In the case of C all `NA` values will become 0 since the first registration is on the last date.

Get something like this:

```
    Date 1   Date 2    Date 3    Date 4    Date 5
  A  0       0.1       0.2        0.2       0.3
  B  0.1     0.2       0.2        0.3       0.2
  C  0       0         0          0         0.3
  D  0.1     0.2       0.3        0.1       0.175
  E  0       0         0.1        0.2        0.1
```

Can you help me? I'm not sure how to do it in R.

EDIT:
what if I want the mean of the values NA is in between? In this case for A, change the NA in Date 4 for the mean of Date 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach, we create an index to `gather` by assigning a `row_number()` to every row. We then `group_by` every `row` and find the first non-NA value in the `row` and `replace` every `NA` value before that to 0 and all other `NA` values after that to `mean`. We finally `spread` the variables back to wide format by removing unnecessary columns created during calculation.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(value1 = replace(value, is.na(value) & row_number() < which.max(!is.na(value)), 0), 
         value2 = replace(value1, is.na(value1), mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-value1, -value) %>%
  spread(key, value2) %>%
  select(-row)


# Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 Date5
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.    0.100 0.200 0.200 0.300
#2 0.100 0.200 0.200 0.300 0.200
#3 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.300
#4 0.100 0.200 0.300 0.100 0.175
#5 0.    0.    0.100 0.200 0.100
```

---

A base R approach using `apply` for each row

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
   inds <- which.max(!is.na(x))
   x[inds:length(x)] <- replace(x[inds:length(x)], is.na(x[inds:length(x)]),
                         mean(x[inds:length(x)], na.rm = TRUE))
  x[1:inds] <- replace(x[1:inds], is.na(x[1:inds]), 0)
  x
}))


#  Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 Date5
#A   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.2 0.300
#B   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.3 0.200
#C   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.300
#D   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1 0.175
#E   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.2 0.100
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another question, what if I want the mean of the values NA is in between? In this case for A, change the NA in Date 4 for the mean of Date 3 and 5.

Comment: @user195366 for that you need to get the closest non-NA value on both the sides and replace it by it's mean and we need to do this for every `NA` value in each row. I would suggest you to add a new question for this.